# Connectivity state security issue

Tags: java, android

So I am making an app and I need to check if the user has an active internet connection. After I followed some example code on the Android Dev Resources, I am recieving an error.

It should be noted that I am using this in a fragment hence the `getActivity()`

Below is the method that I am using to check:

```
public boolean checkForConnection()
{
    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    return isConnected;
}
```

I have also declared the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the context

`getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService`

try to use just the getActivity get getting the getSystemServive

```
ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Excellent. This worked. Quick note though: you put "getSystemService" twice in the code it should be: "ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);"

Comment: @SlashTag mind if you upvote it as well for correct answer.. thank you